How to change/update DataExtensionField's length using ssjs?
i currently have data extension, its customerKEY, data extensionField's objectID, and a soap api call which can implement this (updation/change of data extension field's length)
soapApi code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options />
            <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <CustomerKey>{{CustomerKey}}</CustomerKey>
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <ObjectID>{{ObjectID}}</ObjectID>
                        <MaxLength>250</MaxLength>
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

all i need is to implement this for multiple data extension's field (for more than 500) which can't be done manually or for 500 times also.
Any suggestions for doing this ??

I assume you can get a list of field object IDs where these fields have field type is Text and their Max Length < 250.
Then you can put them in an array and process it through a loop. I would do something like this:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var DEcustKey = "Your DE customer key";

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var lstFieldObjectId = [123, 456, 789] //Put your field ObjectID here;

var fields = []
// Combine them into a JSON
for (var i= 0; i < lstFieldObjectId.length; i++){
    var fieldObj = {"ObjectID":  lstFieldObjectId[i], "MaxLength": 250};
    fields.push(fieldObj)
}

//Update fields
var result = prox.updateItem('DataExtension', {
    "CustomerKey": DEcustKey,
    "Fields": fields
});
</script>

